# What code should be used instead of getche in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am new to c++ ,

What code should i write to make the screen stand still. I use

```
getche();
```

in c language. but instead of `getche()` what should i use in c++;
I tried

```
std::cin.get();
```

but the console windows displays and then goes off quickly.

Comment: `std::cin.get` only extracts one character. If you have one there already, it will extract it and move on.

Answer (score 3):

> the console windows displays and then goes off quickly.

It seems that you have something in your buffer, and `cin.get` is reading that as a character. For example:

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i;
std::cin.get();
```

When you enter number and press Enter, `cin >> i` will consume the number, but it will leave `\n` character (which comes from Enter keystroke) in the buffer which will be read by `std::cin.get()` without waiting for the user to enter new data.

In order to make this example to behave like we want, we need to empty the buffer before calling `std::cin.get()`:

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::cin.get();
```

`std::numeric_limits` is defined in `<limits>` header file.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, I usually uses `system("pause");`, which call the OS's `pause` command, to prevent the console window from being closed after the program terminates. This commands displays a nice message and wait for any key :).

> Press any key to continue . . .

I don't know if the command exists in the other OSes or not, nor I don't know if it is what you're trying to archive :).

The function is in the `cstdlib` or `stdlib.h` header file

Last but not least, it's not really a good idea to call getch() at the last line of code to prevent the console from being closed. But if you really prefer this way, I suggest to use something like

```
std::string temp;
std::cin>>temp;
```

At the ends of your main function, just before `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just include `<stdlib.h>` and in main method use `system("pause")` your console window will remain still.

Comment: Using the call system() is insecure: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following
 getch()

Comment: The OP explicitely asks for c++!